# RoboSpice and android life cycle trouble

Tags: android, caching, robospice

I use robospice like this:

```
ProjectInfoRequest request = new ProjectInfoRequest(mProfile);
spiceManager.execute(request, PROJECT_INFO_LISTENER);
```

It downloads data and almost everything is ok.

However there are some things that makes me unhappy:

- When I press home button, SpiceManager.shouldStop() is called accordingly to the documentation. But when the task is executed listener does not get call, which is right(I guess, because the activity may be destroyed by OS) but how do I save downloaded data? I don't see any in-memory persister in 1.4.0 version
- When I try to specify cacheKey like this

`spiceManager.execute(request, "projectInfo", DurationInMilis.NEVER, PROJECT_INFO_LISTENER);`

the request won't even start executing. However I really need it cause i'd like to use addListenerIfReqeustPending method. What are posible reasons not to start execute request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version do you use ? 1.4.1 has just been released. And which service do you use ? Which cache manager is used by the SpiceService ?

Comment: Good to hear about new version!Congrats! I use 1.4.0. By the time i've asked the question there was no 1.4.1 version in maven repos. I solved my problem using sublcass of SpicedService and a CacheManager with my custom Persister wich holds last request in memory. Is that a good solution or I may have some problems?

Comment: That's a good solution, in could much easier by using pre-built services from RS 1.4.1 with/out a in memory persister (LruPersister).